# Retrieve all albums from a specific year from Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get all albums in a specific year from a fan page on Facebook.  Right now Facebook is giving me in order of the most current album, but what i want is to tell Facebook that i want only albums from 2014, for example.  I'm not finding anything in the Graph API docs, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `since` and `until` request parameters as outlined in

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

like this

```
GET /{page_id}/albums?since=1388534400&until=1420070399
```